# Combining/getting elevations from .asc files or .tiff with x and y locations

Tags: r, lidar, elevation

I am new to R and still getting to know the environment.

I am doing a project in animal movement. I have x and y locations (plus IDs, dates, hours) in an Excel table, converted into .csv as well. I downloaded the data from LiDAR and another web page for the area the animals were moving around at, so I got .asc and .tiff files. Now I need to combine the x and y locations with either of these files to get an elevation for each x and y (elevation will be one of the environmental covariates).

I tried "elevatr" package/guidance but it's only for US and it only shows how to download it from the internet.

Has anyone any idea how to merge or combine these files and get elevations for each location?

I believe there's a very simple way of doing it but as I said, I'm new to this coding and wandering in the dark most of the time.

Comment: You should find a tutorial on spatial data in R - there's lots of them about, but this isn't the right place to ask for recommendations. Look at the `sf` and `raster` packages for basic spatial data handling. As it stands this question is too broad for this site - if you get stuck with something more specific then post a new question focused on that.

Comment: Please, edit Q to provide a reproducible example. Tks.